# how to create softlayer citrix load balancer from SL-API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

i am trying to create a Citrix load balancer my code is :

#

```
LocationForNetscaler = 168642
Netscaler=44958
staticIPAddress=27569
package = 192
ProdcutOrderService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order']
orderContainers ={
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "location": LocationForNetscaler ,
                    "packageId": package,
                    "prices": [
                        {"id": Netscaler,
                         "complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"
                         },
                        {
                         "id":staticIPAddress,
                         "complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"
                         }

                    ]

                }
orderData = {
               'orderContainers' : [orderContainers ]
            }

receipt = ProdcutOrderService.verifyOrder(orderData)
print "Order Verification"
pprint(receipt)
```

#

but i am getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abcd/Downloads/25-05-2016/28-05-2016-test.py", line 84, in 
    receipt = ProdcutOrderService.verifyOrder(orderData)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 373, in call_handler
    return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 341, in call
    return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 237, in call
    return self.transport(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 187, in **call**
    raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
    SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: `SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid): Invalid price Citrix NetScaler VPX 10.5 10Mbps Standard (44958) provided on the order container.`

#

please guide
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) method doesn't identify the type of container that you are sending, try to add a **complexType** property, try this please:

```
LocationForNetscaler = 168642
Netscaler=44958
staticIPAddress=27569
package = 192
productService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order']
orderContainers ={
                    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "location": LocationForNetscaler,
                    "packageId": package,
                    "prices": [
                        {
                         "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price", 
                         "id": Netscaler
                         },
                        {
                         "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price", 
                         "id": staticIPAddress
                         }

                    ]

                }


receipt = productService.verifyOrder(orderContainers)
print(receipt)
```